# Spring RestTemplate gives "500" error but same URL, credentails works in RestClient and Curl

Tags: spring

An Url, Credentials works in RestClient UI as well as with Curl where as i'm getting "500" error when access the same via Spring RestTemplate.

I am using the following code:

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
map.add("name", user);
map.add("password", password);
restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, Employee.class, map);
```

Please let me know your suggestions or comments to fix the problem.

Comment: Does your Employee class really start with a lower case e?

Comment: sorry it is a typo error..It is Employee.class

Comment: 500 is a server error; is there any detail in the body of the response or anything useful in the server's log?

Comment: No. Below is the stack trace for reference:          org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error
 at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:77)
 at

Comment: For Post:
restTemplate.postForObject(url, parametersMap, Employee.class);
url is : String - rest api URL
parametersMap - MultiValueMap<String, String>
Employee - object which needs to be converted from the JSON response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below works fine

For Post:

restTemplate.postForObject(url, parametersMap, Employee.class);

url is : String - rest api URL 
parametersMap - MultiValueMap 
Employee - object which needs to be converted from the JSON response

Answer (score 18):

I would suggest to create your `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` and pass it to your `RestTemplate` as described below:

```
ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new     
      HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClients.createDefault());

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```

By this way, you would avoid server-side issues (like facing error code 500) when testing your application.

I had the same issue that worked in my local environment and not on the server.

It is a good practice to pass `HttpClients.createDefault()` to your `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` while constructing it since by default, this factory uses system properties to create `HttpClient` for your factory and that may cause lots of pain in real server environment. You may also pass your custom `HttpClient`.

Comment: hi, what is the HttpClients object please? I cant find any maven dependency that will let me import this. I am trying to use RestTemplateXhrTransport to connect to a websocket and i am getting the error above. thanks

Comment: Sorry! It is a bit late to answer but as far as I remember, It belonged to one of the following projects (based on priority). You can try each and see if you get compiler error;
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
 <version>....</version>
</dependency>
Or
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
 <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
 <version>....</version>
</dependency>
Or
<dependency>
 <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
 <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
 <version>...</version>
</dependency>

Comment: @DuncanJones It is explained in Spring Framework Issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9367

Answer (score 11):

```
RestTemplate header Accept problem 
--> accept - text/plain, application/json, */*

HttpClient 4.x header Accept
--> accept - application/json
```

so i fixed

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
```

http://www.manning-sandbox.com/message.jspa?messageID=119733

Answer (score 5):

I have also faced a situation where server response was **"500 Internal server error"**

Though I have received success response from **Postman** for the same parameter value.
So the problem was not in server side.

The problem was typo in parameter name, **mismatch spelling between application parameter and server parameter**

```
Server parameter        -> requestLabel
Application parameter   -> requestLable
```

Hope someone new like me get help from this.

Comment: This helped me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This may happen if your data contract class is missing default constructor - so Jackson fails to construct it. You can try solve this issue by adding a **private** default constructor to your class (despite it is private, Jackson will be able to construct your class instance).

Answer (score 1):

You are passing name and password as uri variable:

```
public <T> T postForObject(java.lang.String url,
                                     @Nullable
                                     java.lang.Object request,
                                     java.lang.Class<T> responseType,
                                     java.util.Map<java.lang.String,?> uriVariables)

                          throws RestClientException
```

[docs.spring.io](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#postForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-)

If you had some url like:
**http://yourhost:8080/dosomethingwithemployee/name/password** and you extracted name&password from url itself, then it probably would work.

```
String url = "http://yourhost:8080/dosomethingwithemployee/{name}/{password}"
restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, Employee.class, map);
```

However, I think you have been trying to send name and password in request body:

```
public SomeType getResponse(String login, String password) {
        MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setName(login);
        employee.setPassword(password);
        SomeType responseBody = post("http://locahost:8080/dosomethingwithemployee", employee, headers, SomeType.class);
        return responseBody;
    }

    public <T> T post(String url, Object requestObject, MultiValueMap<String, String> headers, Class<T> responseType) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());

        HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(requestObject, headers);
        T responseObject = restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, responseType);

        return responseObject;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Though its too late to answer, below solution will help someone if above solutions did not work.
For me, the error was with Request object and its header.
Your request object should generate JSON as required by api. It should not have any extra field or additional getter method.
In my case, I had additional getter method which was adding unnecessary field to request

```
postForEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri,entity,String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an external library/sdk that uses rest service (like Twilio), it can override the JSON structure.

It may be a solution to downgrade the version of the relevant package.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue. Restarting my local server reset the connection and solved the problem for me.