# java.net.HttpRetryException: cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode

Tags: java, http, servlets

We have two parts in our app:
Server - provide REST services
Client - consume them via Spring restTemplate

In addition to the HTTP status our server returns an HTTP body with JSON that describe error in detail.
So, I've added custom Error handler to restTemplate to treat some error coded as non errors - it helps parse HTTP body very well.

But I get an exception via parsing of the HTTP body in the case of an HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized.
All other error codes are handled fine(400, 402, etc. )
We are using plain server logic that sends HTTP response in the case of an error, no special rules for different types of an error:

```
writeErrorToResponse(int status, String errMsg, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        response.setStatus(status);
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        String message = String.format("{\"error\":\"%s\"}", StringUtils.escapeJson(errMsg));
        resp.getWriter().println(message);
    }
```

But on client only HTTP/1.1 401 throws exception - `"java.net.HttpRetryException: cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode"`

I've made some debugging and see that the cause of the problem is code in SimpleClientHttpResponse:

HttpURLConnection.getInputStream()

Tracing with Fiddler have these next responses:
Message is parsed correct on the client:

```
HTTP/1.1 402 Payment Required
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Language: en-GB
Content-Length: 55
Connection: Close
Date: Sat, 25 May 2013 10:10:44 GMT
Server: WebSphere Application Server/8.0

{"error":"I cant find that user.  Please try again."}
```

And message that is cause of exception:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Language: en-GB
Content-Length: 55
Date: Sat, 25 May 2013 11:00:21 GMT
Server: WebSphere Application Server/8.0

{"error":"I cant find that user.  Please try again."}
```

What could be the cause of java.net.HttpRetryException in this situation?

**In addition**: Some times ago this mechanism worked fine. But since we have changed a lot of code in app.

Comment: I am having the same problem... How to resolve this???

Comment: I've make workaround: 1) Added in custom error handler to handle 403 as error. 2) Catch thrown exception and handle 403 error code. But not possible to parse HTTP body in this case.

Comment: @user1182217 see my answer above

Comment: Someone already raised issue in Spring Framework. But it was closed, I am reopening it. Please vote for it:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16781

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This issue is reported in Spring Framework.

**Reference**:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9367

**Copying from Reference:**
It is very difficult (impossible) to handle a 401 response in the RestTemplate with default settings. In fact it is possible, but you have to supply an error handler and a request factory. The error handler was obvious, but the problem is that the default request factory uses java.net which can throw HttpRetryException when you try to look at the status code of the response (despite it being obviously available). The solution is to use HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory. E.g.

```
template.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
template.setErrorHandler(new DefaultResponseErrorHandler() {
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        HttpStatus statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
        return statusCode.series() == HttpStatus.Series.SERVER_ERROR;
    }
});
```

HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requires below dependency. Add below dependency in your POM file:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this! This is the only way that I could manage to test my rest enpoint protected with the 'basic authentication'.

Comment: Lifesaver, not sure how is one supposed to figure this out on their own?

Answer (score 36):

I faced the same issue when using [SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.html). Solved it by setting

```
SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
requestFactory.setOutputStreaming(false);
return requestFactory;
```

The problem is due to chunking and subsequent retry mechanism incase of authentication.

You can also disable chunks using HttpClientPolicy

Comment: With the spring web version 6.1, `setOutputStreaming` is deprecated and is a noop. Use `org.springframework.http.client.JdkClientHttpRequestFactory` instead which doesn't have this weird behavior.

Answer (score 19):

I was having the exact same issue using Spring Boot 2.2.4 and a TestRestTemplate. It only failed on 401's. Simply adding the latest version of [Http Client (4.5.11)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.11) in a test scope fixed the problem.  No further configuration was necessary.

Comment: With the latest Spring Boot version (3.2.2) including [httpclient5 - 5.3.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents.client5/httpclient5/5.3.1) in the test dependencies worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

I think passing a configured HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory to your RestTemplate would help.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29467839/1572286) you might find the solution on how to do it.

The reason that I used such development solution was to handle the response messages in the body of Http error responses like 401, 404, and so on, and also to let the application be deployed on real-server side environment.

Answer (score 1):

This exception has a quite unexpected impact on Spring OAuth2 token retrieval. For this retrieval the standard implementation uses `RestTemplate` which is configured with `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` where output streaming set to true. If the 4XX authentication error happens , the standard `ResponseErrorHandler` tries to read the output stream and receives, of course, the discussed exception, but decides to silently consume it, ignore.
Sometimes, however, OAuth2 authentication server writes important information into the output/error stream which must be read and analyzed.
To make this information available, upon the creation of `OAuth2RestTemplate`, its `AccessTokenProvider` should be set to a custom one, let's name it `ErrorStreamAwareAccessTokenProvider`:

```
oauth2RestTemplate.setAccessTokenProvider(new ErrorStreamAwareAccessTokenProvider());
```

and this custom `AccessTokenProvider` should overwrite, e.g. `getRestTemplate` method and tune the `RestTemplate` correspondingly, as the accepted answers advise. For example:

```
class ErrorStreamAwareAccessTokenProvider extends OAuth2AccessTokenSupport{
    // your exact superclass may vary depending on grant type and other things
    protected RestOperations getRestTemplate() {
        RestTemplate template = super.getRestTemplate();
        template.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
        // ... also set ResponseErrorHandler if needed
        return template; 
    }
}
```

When this is done, the standard `ResponseErrorHandler` could read the output/error stream or, if you want, for example, to throw a custom exception which has the retrieved information stored in it, you could set your custom `ResponseErrorHandler` in the above overwritten method.

Answer (score 1):

Since Spring Framework 6.1, the `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` [doesnt](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/30557) support toggling the streaming anymore, e.g. following doesn't work any longer:

```
SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory simpleClientHttpRequestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
simpleClientHttpRequestFactory.setOutputStreaming(false);
```

Instead you should use JdkClientHttpRequestFactory by checking out [Spring's release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What%27s-New-in-Spring-Framework-6.x).

Especially [HttpClient based ClientHttpRequestFactory](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/30478) and [Remove buffering in ClientHttpRequestFactory implementations](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/30557).

Comment: The way to configure some of these `ClientHttpRequestFactory`s for Spring Boot is explained in the release notes [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.2-Release-Notes#resttemplate-http-clients).