# Getting java.net.HttpRetryException: cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode

Tags: spring, spring-test

I've created a test for the creation of a new user:

```
private static String USERS_ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:8080/users/";
private static String GROUPS_ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:8080/groups/";

@Test
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public void whenCreateAppUser() {

    AppUser appUser = new AppUser();
    appUser.setUsername("test@example.com");
    appUser.setPassword("password");

    // Throws java.net.HttpRetryException
    template.postForEntity(USERS_ENDPOINT, appUser, AppUser.class);

    ResponseEntity<AppUser> appUserResponse = template.getForEntity(USERS_ENDPOINT + "1/", AppUser.class);

    assertEquals("Username is incorrect. AppUser not created?",
            appUser.getUsername(), appUserResponse.getBody().getUsername());
}
```

However, for some reason I am getting:

```
Caused by: java.net.HttpRetryException: cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1692)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getRawStatusCode(SimpleClientHttpResponse.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.hasError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:49)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:735)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:700)
    ... 34 more
```

For the call

```
template.postForEntity(USERS_ENDPOINT, appUser, AppUser.class);
```

I actually don't know what I changed because this used to work for me. Any idea what causes this issue?

---

My `WebSecurity` settings are:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

    final String[] SWAGGER_UI = {
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/v2/api-docs",
            "/webjars/**"
    };

    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/pub/**", "/users")
            .antMatchers(SWAGGER_UI);
}
```

Comment: As a side note, the JavaDoc for `classMode` in `@DirtiesContext` clearly states the following: _Setting the class mode on an annotated test method has no meaning. For method-level control, use `methodMode` instead._

Comment: It sounds like you're attempting to make a request that requires an authenticated user. Have you recently switched on security in your web app?

Comment: @SamBrannen Yes, I did but I actually ignore this particular endpoint (see edit). I can make this call from my webclient - which works - only the unit test won't do it's part - oh the irony. Thanks for the hint regarding `methodMode`!

Comment: What happens if you drop the trailing slash in the users URL in your test like this `"http://localhost:8080/users"`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Spring's `RestTemplate` and Spring Boot's `TestRestTemplate` will on JDK's internal `HttpURLConnection` implementation by default, which **fails to access the *body* of an HTTP-response with status 401 "Unauthorized".**

A magical **solution is to include Apache's HTTP Client into the classpath** — e.g. with Maven,

- **For Spring Boot 3.x.x:**

  ```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  ```
- **For Spring Boot 2.x.x:**

  ```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  ```

In this case, Spring (Boot) will use Apache's HTTP Client which doesn't face the problem.

---

See also: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/441#issuecomment-92033542

Comment: Also upgrade your spring boot version

Comment: It didn't solve my problem, I used `restOperations.exchange(request, responseType)`, and it gave me the same error when unauthorized.

Comment: @RDK then you should post a new question with your specific problem.

Comment: It didn't work for me because by default a new instance of OAuth2RestTemplate used SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory and even though I created  HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory bean in the configuration it was not used, so I set it manually using `oAuth2RestTemplateInstance.setRequestFactory(httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory_bean)`

Comment: The same as for @RDK :  I use BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory, so I added to config: `restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory()));`

Answer (score 5):

Using the HttpClient from the Apache HttpComponents Client library solved the issue for me.

To use the Apache HttpClient you have to configure your RestTemplate the following way:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Configuration
public class RestClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        var template = new RestTemplate();

        template.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());

        return template;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As answered in [java.net.HttpRetryException: cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748969/java-net-httpretryexception-cannot-retry-due-to-server-authentication-in-strea)

an alternative is:

```
SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
requestFactory.setOutputStreaming(false);
return requestFactory;
```