# Spring tool suite - console error - whitelabel Error page - access denied

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Spring boot sample program with Mysql backend. very simple code. I checked application. properties, access to the DB etc. No clue why I am getting this error.

POM.XML

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
         <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
         <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
 <groupId>com.skb.course.apis</groupId>
<artifactId>library-apis</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>library-apis</name>
<description>Project for developing Library APIs</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JPA Data (We are going to use Repositories, Entiries, Hibernate, etc...) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For MySQL Connector-J -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For implementing API Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For handling JWT related functionality-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test related dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Used for Integration Tests. Spring's TestRestTemplate throws an error while sending PUT requests with
     authorization error: java.net.HttpRetryException: cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode
     Therefore we need to use Apaches's HTTP client. Please refer:
     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748969/java-net-httpretryexception-cannot-retry-due-to-server-authentication-in-stream
        -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[image]

Console has no errors and tomcat is configured to run on 3000 port

[image]

application.properties file

[image]

Mysql db showing list of databaseds

[image]

Theere is data available in the PUBLISHER TABLE. but access denied error is thrown

[image]

Rest controller code

```
package com.skb.course.apis.libraryapis.publisher;

 import org.slf4j.Logger;
 import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
 import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
 import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

 import javax.validation.Valid;
 import java.util.UUID;

 @RestController
 @RequestMapping(path = "/v1/publishers")
 public class PublisherController {

 private static Logger logger = 
 LoggerFactory.getLogger(PublisherController.class);

 private PublisherService publisherService;

   public PublisherController(PublisherService publisherService) {
    this.publisherService = publisherService;
   }

   @GetMapping(path = "/{publisherId}")
   public ResponseEntity<?> getPublisher(@PathVariable Integer publisherId,
        @RequestHeader(value = "Trace-Id", defaultValue = "") String traceId)
        throws LibraryResourceNotFoundException {

    if (!LibraryApiUtils.doesStringValueExist(traceId)) {
        traceId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(publisherService.getPublisher(publisherId, traceId), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you share rest controller with mapping /v1/publishers/{number}

Comment: If you are using maven could you share you pom.xml? Please check whether you have right spring security configurations if you have included any security related starters

Comment: gungor, I added the controller code in my orginal post

Comment: Remove Spring Security dependency (spring-boot-starter-security) from your pom.xml and then try again!

Comment: Onur, thank for responding. when I remove the spring-boot-starter-security, it throws so many error in the project structure. this is the sample code from a Udemy course. You suspect something with that dependency?